# Is there a function that triggers UIImagePickerController to take a photo?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to trigger the camera with a non-standard button.

What function do I call to trigger the camera?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the Overlay view  property of the  UIImagePickerController to specify your own view, you can use the -takePicture method to trigger the camera to take a picture [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/takePicture) is a reference, hope it helps